# VBA is it possible to get location of keyword on IE webpage

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use VBA to open up a webpage for me (this webpage is made up of HTML with cells of data), find some keywords, and email out the keywords and a certain number of rows of data above and below the keywords. To do this though, I need to be able to find the location of the keywords (eg. row 3, column 2, or line 4 characters 4-10, etc.). Are there any commands in the Internet Explorer Library that will allow me to do this? So far I have code for one keyword only, that will go to the keyword and select/highlight it. Now I need to find out how to grab a certain amount of rows above/below it and send it out.

Also a side question: If you know a good way to modify my current code to create a nested loop that scans through the whole webpage, and for multiple keywords that would be very helpful!

```
Sub subFindScrollIE()

Dim boolFound As Boolean



    Dim ie As InternetExplorer

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    ie.Navigate "my URL HERE"

    strTemp = "KEYWORD1"

    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

        'DoEvents

    Loop

    ie.Visible = True

    Set txt = ie.Document.body.createTextRange()

    boolFound = txt.findText(strTemp)

    txt.moveStart "character", -1

    txt.findText strTemp

    txt.Select

    txt.ScrollIntoView




    Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: "html with cells of data"? You mean an html table or a div? html itself has no "cells".

Comment: I meant table, apologies. It's just that the table is 1x1 so it appears as a cell.

Comment: you can loop through table elements in html and then once you found where the keyword is in the table you can grab information from x rows above or below that row. It will most likely take some trial and error, but it's possible.

Comment: You are talking about how to grab a certain amount of **rows of table** or **lines of text** above/below the keyword? Rows and lines are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could continue with the approach you have started using if you use Regular Expressions to locate the text you are after and the surrounding text.

Personally, I would favor using html objects to find what you're after.  Here is some example code to iterate through generic tables:

```
Sub subFindScrollIE()

    Dim strTemp() As Variant, output() As String, txt As String
    Dim tr As HTMLTableRow, r As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim tRows As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim xlR As Byte, c As Byte
    Dim ie As InternetExplorerMedium

    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "E:\Dev\table.htm"

    strTemp = Array("abc", "mno", "vwx", "efg")

    Do Until (ie.ReadyState = 4 Or ie.ReadyState = 3): Loop

    Set tRows = ie.Document.body.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    xlR = 2

    ' loop through rows
    For r = 0 To tRows.Length - 1

        Set tr = tRows(r)

        ' loop through search text
        For i = 0 To UBound(strTemp)

            ' search row for string
            txt = LCase(tr.innerHTML)
            If (InStr(txt, LCase(strTemp(i))) > 0) Then

                ' search string found. split table data into array
                txt = tr.innerHTML
                txt = Replace(txt, "</td><td>", "~")
                txt = Replace(txt, "<td>", "")
                txt = Replace(txt, "</td>", "")
                output = Split(txt, "~")

                ' populate cells from array
                For c = 0 To UBound(output)
                    Sheet1.Cells(xlR, c + 2) = output(c)
                Next c
                xlR = xlR + 2
            End If
        Next i
    Next r

    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This is so close to what I need! Thank you so much. What I just realized is that the surrounding data around the keywords that I am looking for are all in one div of the HTML table, so I only need to pull out THAT html row, not any before or below it. So how do I change the code to do this? I am assuming it's one of those lines in the IF statement that needs to be removed?

Comment: Never mind, I commented out the first and third lines in the IF statement and it outputs exactly what I need in the immediate window. What is the best way to output this data? Do you think it would be best to put it into excel and email that out?

Comment: just to play around with it, I did activecell.value = stroutput and activecell.offset(0,1).Select, so i could see it on an excel sheet. For some reason when I straight up run the entire code altogether, only the first match is found and fills cell A1 (there are 4 total keyword matches on the URL), but when I step through the code by using F8 all four matches are found and put into excel and fill A1:D1. Do you have any idea why that is?

Comment: If your target text is always in a div, you can change the tag Name search to collate a collection of `div` elements. (You will need to make further changes too.) I don't suppose your target div has an `id` attribute? If so, you can skip all the searching and jump straight to it.

Comment: It is difficult to advise on the optimal output without knowing more about the data. If it works well in Excel, then that would be the easiest destination, but you will want to put it in a separate workbook (an flax file) to avoid sending out your VBA code. Another option would be to create a webpage, but this would take a fair bit of work to sepulchre style. I guess it comes down to your target audience - are you sure they have Excel and would a webpage be easier for them to work with?

Comment: The code above has only one output. Each string that is found adds a new table to that output. When it runs free, it probably finds all four keywords and puts the amalgamated output into a single cell. (Try expanding the row height to test this.) I guess you have amended the code to use your offset, but I can't comment on that without seeing the code.

Comment: excel is the best output. i simply want to email out each 'chunk' of data the keyword is in to let the end user know there is something that needs to be checked further. Also, I did try expanding the cell and it seems that only one keyword match is outputted, rather than all 4. I wonder why this is. When i step through the code it works just fine. hmm

Comment: I am trying to rewrite the for loop to lop through each row instead of each table since there is only one table..for the line of code "Set tRows = tbl.Rows," I am not sure what to replace it with. I want to code 'one step further down' so do something like tCells = tRows.Rows, but obviously it is not .Rows, do you know what it should be? Thanks 

btw: this is inside the loop "For each trow In allrows" where allrows = ie.Document.body.getElementByTagName("tr")

Comment: I've updated the answer to just search rows. If a match is found, the html tags are removed and used to split the data into an array to populate separate columns.  This code will still work if the table row only has a single cell (which I suspect is the case as it is contained in a div element).  One thing that could interfere with the text manipulation is any formatting between html cells, but we can tackle that if needed.